# Two day discrepancy with JPA, EclipseLink and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, jpa, eclipselink

When pulling dates from a view using JPA and EclipseLink I'm getting dates two days before the date in the SQL data. (ie 1965-01-01 becomes 1964-12-30 and 1998-12-31 becomes 1998-12-29)

I am mapping date fields in SQL Server 2008 R2 with the following annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vw_Record")
@XmlRootElement
public class VwRecord implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "dateStart")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateStart;

    @Column(name = "dateEnd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateEnd;
```

The columns in SQL Server are defined as:

```
[dateStart] [date] NULL,
[dateEnd] [date] NULL
```

Any ideas why I am getting a consistent two day difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink does not do any conversion, it is most likely occurring in JDBC.

You can trying executing a native SQL query through JPA and see what data it returns.  Also try selecting the data through raw JDBC.

Comment: JPA Native SQL query is doing the same thing, as is JDBC call. Looks like Microsoft's JDBC driver is at fault. Thanks.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx for more info and hotfix.